# WhatsApp. How it works?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

My friend recently downloaded WhatsApp to his Iphone. Anyone can tell me technically how it works? Does it use the same technology as PushMail? How can it stay in the background? I am not a Iphone Developer, btw.

Comment: APNS is not related to programming?

Comment: I agree.  This *is* related to programming in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it but it looks like it is using [APNS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/apns.html). This allows you to display notifications even though the app is not running

> Send a message with text that lets the user launch your app. Trigger audible alerts with your own custom sounds